# Using threads to count all occurrences of a substring

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Supposing that I have t threads, what is the optimal solution for counting all non-overlapping occurrences of a substring T in a string S?

*This is a chunk of code that does the normal count, but I'm not sure how to implement it concurrently. What would happen if t is smaller than length of the substring?*

```
public class Substrings {
public int countOccurrences(String S, String T) {
  int count = 0, offset = 0, index;
  while((index = S.indexOf(T, offset)) != -1) {
    offset = index + T.length();
            count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

}

Comment: When you want to count all non-overlapping occurrences *efficiently*, use `int count = 0; Matcher m = Pattern.compile(T, Pattern.LITERAL).matcher(S); while(m.find()) count++; return count;` using the regex [`Pattern` class](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) allowing it to spent effort in preparation. In practice, this means using the [Boyer–Moore algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string-search_algorithm) internally which may have a bigger benefit than parallel processing.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to do this as operations like this are pretty fast, unless you have alot of giant Strings. The optimal solution is not something I want to think about, but there is a simple way to do this that's about twice as slow as the optimal. Split the String up into sections and run countOccurrences on each section using a thread. Put all the indexes you found into a Set. Then slide the sections forward half the length of a section and do it again. This second part will find any occurrences that span sections. Of course you could limit this second search by the length of the String on both sides, but this would complicate the code. As an exercise, perhaps you can do this with Boyer-Moore.

Comment: I don’t understand why you think sliding the sections “half the length of a section” will guarantee to find the right non-overlapping matches that cross the old section border. The potential positions of such matches depend on the search string length and the actual positions of previous matches. Further, such a section border crossing match could overlap with a match previously found in the next section, invalidating it, which could in turn invalidate all subsequent matches. So a splitting strategy is only beneficial if you can disprove overlapping matches for the search string in advance.

Comment: I see what you mean. It's a bit tricky, isn't it? Maybe the thing to do is to solve the easier problem of finding all matches first, then eliminate the overlapping matches by looking at the indexes and the string length?

Comment: That would raise the costs more than the multi-threading could even compensate.